# jquery ajax form plugin submit multiple times to the server only when using IE6

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, submit, internet-explorer-6

I all.
I have the following form used to temporarily upload a photo on a j2ee server and then crop it with imageAreaSelect plugin :

```
<form name="formAvatarName" id="formAvatar" method="post" 
action="../admin/admin-avatar-upload" 
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label>Upload a Picture of Yourself</label>
<input type="file" name="upload" id="upload" size="20" />
<input type="button" id="formAvatarSubmit" value="formAvatar" onclick="invia()"/> 
</form>
```

I am using jquery form plugin to do ajax submission, this is my last :) attempt :

```
var options = { 
    beforeSubmit:  showRequest,  // pre-submit callback 
    success:       showResponse,  // post-submit callback 
    dataType:  'text/html' 
}; 

   $('#formAvatar').unbind('submit').bind('submit', function() {
     alert('aho');
        $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
        return false;
   });
```

Here below the javascript functions used as submit event handlers:

```
    function showRequest(formData, jqForm, options) { 
        var queryString = $.param(formData); 
        log.debug('About to submit: \n\n' + queryString); 
        return true; 
    } 

    function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form)  { 
        myRes=responseText; 
        log.debug('status: ' + statusText + '\n\nresponseText: \n' + responseText); 


        //box uploaded
        $('div#avatar-upl > img').replaceWith(myRes);
        var origWidth = $('div#avatar-upl > img').width();
        var origHeight = $('div#avatar-upl > img').height();
        log.debug('AjaxUpload onComplete(): orig size w,h : ' + origWidth + ', ' + origHeight);

        //scaling uploaded
        $('div#avatar-upl > img').jScale(
                {ls:'300px'}, 
        function(){
                var scaleWidth = $(this).width();
                var scaleHeight = $(this).height();
                log.debug('AjaxUpload onComplete(): scaled size w,h : ' + scaleWidth + ', ' + scaleHeight);
                //put scaled sizes on img custom attribute, to be retrieved from preview() method
            $('div#avatar-upl > img').attr('scaleWidth', scaleWidth);
                $('div#avatar-upl > img').attr('scaleHeight', scaleHeight);
            }
        );

        //box thumbnail
        $('div#avatar-thumb > img').replaceWith(myRes);
        $('div#avatar-thumb > img').css({
        width: 100,
        height: 100
    });

    //setup of imgAreaSelect
    $('div#avatar-upl > img').imgAreaSelect({ 
        handles: true, 
        onSelectEnd: avatarPreview
    }); 
}
```

This is the html :

```
<div id="avatar-mng">
    <div id="avatar-upl">
        <img id="img-upl" style="margin: 0 0.3em;" src="../res/img/spacer.gif" />
    </div>  

    <div id="avatar-thumb" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; overflow: hidden; float:right;">
        <img id="img-thumb" src="../res/img/spacer.gif" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" />
    </div>
    <form name="formAvatarName" id="formAvatar" method="post" action="../admin/admin-avatar-upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label>Upload a Picture of Yourself</label>
        <input type="file" name="upload" id="upload" size="20" />
        <input type="button" id="formAvatarSubmit" value="formAvatar" onclick="invia()"/> 
    </form>
</div>
```

Only when tested with IE6 I can see that the sumbission to the server is done multiple times (first time I got the uploaded file, the other times the sumbmission seems empty and I got error). With IE7, IE8, FFOX, CHROME is working fine.

Any Ideas? 
Many thank in advance!

Comment: Is your "aho" alert popping up twice?

Comment: my alert is popping up only once

Comment: What is the error on the empty submissions ?
How can you see that when IE6, there are multiple submissions ?

ps.: you should show the alert("Update your browser") when IE6 =P

Comment: I have struts on the server side; by using breakpoints on the action I am able to see the multiple submissions.

Comment: Unfortunately, IE6 is the browser standard our application must adhere to.

Answer (score 0):

It seems very likely that you're not getting as far as `return false` -- thus IE goes ahead and submits the form in the "natural" way, as well as by `ajaxSubmit()`. Your `options` specify a `success` callback. What does `showResponse()` look like? Perhaps something in showResponse() is tripping up IE so that it fails to run `return false`. I'd start by trying your code without the success callback, and going from there.